# How do I create a file system / partition / volume that would appear in the side bar of my file manager?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, mount, lubuntu, mountpoint

Is there a specific mount point to use for a partition so that it would appear separately in the side pane?

I mean that it would appear **separately in the left pane of PCManFM or Thunar the way windows-partition and external usb devices appear**.

(I do not mean it being the `/home` partition. Nor it being something like `/boot` because this would not display it as a partition on the left pane but it would look as a folder with that address (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/205105/47206) question). Would (any) such partition be kept after reinstall? Are there possible mount points with any name after `/` - like `/somename`? I wonder whether what I ask here is possible. I guess this question is very contaminated by the Windows experience.)

Here's a picture of the left pane in pcmanfm with the Windows partition (not mounted yet)

[image: left pane of file manager]

P.S. This question is not about changing my present partitions, I just want to know if that is possible. I'm in Lubuntu 12.10.

**Edit after answer and comments:**

I have an answer+comments saying that the partition **should not have a mount point specified** in order to achieve the asked result. **How to create a partition (whether during or after install procedure) without setting the mount-point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are only non-linux partitions (Windows and external drives) displayed as such in the left pane of PCManFM and Thunar?

No. Format a USB flash drive as Ext3/4 and you'll see it appear there too. If you would have another partition on your hard drive without any mount point specified in `/etc/fstab` it would appear there too.

The way the file manager mounts and manages the mounts as shown in the sidebar, has nothing to do with the system mounts. It's about *what* is mounting it. Using

```
gvfs-mount -l
```

you can see which are already managed by your desktop environment. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/56430/88802) and the manpage of gvfs-mount will explain quite well how to mount filesystems the command-line way the same way as your file manager does that programmatically.

GVFS uses FUSE, an user space level filesystem approach, rather than in-kernel. It's about who manages the mounts on your system. The regular GUI file manager does not manage the system mounts (`cat /proc/mounts`) by design.

> Would (any) such partition be kept after reinstall?

Completely unrelated. This is an option in the installer.

Comment: @cipricus No, the answer is no. I have an internal hard drive with a Ext4 partition. It shows up in any file manager there as I don't have it managed by my system. But if you would have rephrased to "will it hide volumes managed by fstab?" then it would be Yes.

Comment: so, a "partition on your hard drive without any mount point specified" it would appear there? can one create a partition during install without setting a mount point? i thought that no. **how you create such partition?** in fact **that** was my question, because i thought that some special path had to be written for the mount point (instead of `/` or `/home` etc) to get that specific result.

Comment: @cipricus Yes. Using any partition editor and creating a filesystem on it (e.g. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX9`). The installer also allows you to in the advanced mode and not setting any mount point. However, I prefer to do things myself afterwards and not fiddle with partitions not needed at installation time. *If the bold part of your comment above was your question to ask, then why did you ask something else?*

Comment: well, could you add that into your answer? i guess **that** is the definitive answer to my question, if you only could detail a bit the phrase "Using any partition editor and creating a filesystem on it (e.g. mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX9)" as answer.

Comment: Your question was suggesting too much towards a wrong solution/answer as you were looking in the wrong direction. If I understand you correctly, your question should have been "How do I create a file system / partition / volume that would appear in the side bar of my file manager?". It's answered here: [Need to create a Partition after installing Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/178638/88802).

Comment: i have put the name you suggested. but the linked question/answer only says: create free space and format it. Would that create a partition visible as asked? Aren't any specific formatting/settings needed for that? i mean those advanced settings you mentioned in previous comment on not setting any mount point (that would be the answer)

Comment: also, considering "Would (any) such partition be kept after reinstall? - Completely unrelated. This is an option in the installer." - what option is that